# How to delete a dynamic array with my function class?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

Again with templates. Now I'm trying to write a `Deleter` function class so that it works similar to the language one `delete`. Here is my attempt:

```
class Deleter
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T*) const;
};

template <typename T>
void Deleter::operator()(T* ptr) const
{
    std::cout << "freeing memory...\n";
    delete ptr;
}


int main()
{

    int* pi = new int(7);
    char* cp = new char[100];
    strcpy(cp, "hi there!");

    Deleter del;
    del(pi); // 1- argument deduced is int*
    del(cp); // 2- argument deduced is char*

    std::cout << "\ndone\n";
}
```

I've overloaded the call operator as a template thus at compile time it knows the static type of argument. (I could made it non-template replacing `T` with `void*`).

It works fine but I think surely that `statement 2` will cause a Memory leak because I am passing a pointer to a dynamic array into `delete` which works on pointers to dynamic object not array and as I've already learned it is undefined behavior to call delete on an object that had not been allocated with the corresponding `new` operator.

So Is there a workaround in my code so that I can call `del[]cp;`? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need to do any of this instead of using standard library containers which manage the memory on their own?

Comment: @UnholySheep: Just for practice. After all I prefer using smart pointers as much as possible.

Comment: Practicing what exactly? You cannot deduce from a pointer in what way it has been allocated, that information is not available there

Comment: I don't see an easy solution. The information on whether it was allocated via new or new[] is not available.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: feels so genius! could you elaborate an example please?

Comment: You could create a second class called ArrayDeleter and have the delete in operator() use [] like `delete [] ptr;`

Comment: @drescherjm that won't work, since the `operator()` won't know if the pointer needs to be freed via `delete` or `delete[]`.  You need separate `operator()` specializations for each type of deletion.

Comment: @Maestro see the answer I just posted.

Comment: I meant a completely different class with a different operator() where you use the Deleter() class for objects created with new and the ArrayDeleter class for objects created with new[].

Comment: @drescherjm yes, you would need two separate classes, one for each type of deletion

Comment: I do like your answer better anyways..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `delete` with memory allocated with `new[]`, and vice versa using `delete[]` with memory allocated with `new`. This is exactly why `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` have specializations to decide when to use `delete[]` vs `delete` for array and non-array memory, respectively (via the [`std::default_delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete) template).

You are just going to have to specialize your `Deleter` in a similar manner, too.  Only the user of your `Deleter`, not the `Deleter` itself, can decide which specialization to use, since only the user has information about how the memory was allocated to begin with, and thus how it needs to be freed.

For example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Deleter
{
public:
    void operator()(T* ptr) const {
        std::cout << "freeing memory using 'delete'...\n";
        delete ptr;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Deleter<T[]>
{
public:
    template <typename U>
    void operator()(U* ptr) const {
        std::cout << "freeing memory using 'delete[]'...\n";
        delete[] ptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int* pi = new int(7);
    char* cp = new char[100];
    strcpy(cp, "hi there!");

    Deleter<int> del1;
    del1(pi); // uses 'delete'...

    Deleter<char[]> del2;
    del2(cp); // uses 'delete[]'...

    std::cout << "\ndone\n";
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/iye2mL)

Comment: so can I call it with an r-value this way: `Deleter<char[]>()(cp);?`

Comment: @Maestro Yes.  Though consider using `{}` instead of `()` when constructing the `Deleter` object, eg: `Deleter<char[]>{}(cp);` But both ways will work.

Comment: Ah yes to avoid the vexing parser?